# FAN Interstital with AdMob Open Bidding not working

Tags: android-studio, admob, facebook-audience-network

So, I integrated Facebook Audience Network with AdMob Mediation. The waterfall ads work fine, however open bidding ads are not working.[image]

[image: Reults from Mediation Test Suite]

I have tried all ways and still could not fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @star_war did you find any solution?

Comment: please someone find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved mine by creating the app-ads.txt on the root of my developer website on playstore and uploaded both the code provided by AdMob and Facebook. Waited for several hours for admob to crawl the app-ads.txt changes and tried testing the mediation and everything worked.

```
facebook.com, fan_id, DIRECT, fan_id
google.com, pub-a_id, DIRECT, a_id
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Should it be RESELLER instead of DIRECT for facebook?